# Windows DNS - redirect all external requests for same ip

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

I'm trying to setup a Windows 2008 DNS Server to redirect all requests for the same IP. For example, if I enter in ANY domain (.com / .net / .org / .us / .uk / ...) I want to redirect the request for the same page. I tried doing this by creating one Forward Lookup Zone with the name "." (root) and adding a Host (A) with the IP I want redirect to. But didn't worked. How can I solve this issue? Remembering the requests will come from WAN and not LAN.
Thank you!

Comment: I honestly don't know if Microsoft DNS services can host TLDs like that, I suspect not. But, I am curious why you are trying to do this and what you are trying to accomplish?  Maybe I/we can help with that?

Comment: I'm working for a college project (not as student but as developer) and they asked me to make a client to run in their students computers and using the current configuration of the college network (LAN), that use this DNS which is already configured for LAN to work this way. This way when the student open the client he will NEED to authenticate in the college system (remotely via browser) and the DNS will control the queries for some specific purposes...

Comment: Maybe is there anyway to redirect '.com' or '.net' requests...

Comment: A much better way to do this is using a captive portal. Thwarting DNS won't atop savvy users from changing DNS and skipping over your DNS hack.

Comment: Yes I was reading right now about captive portal. I need to setup it in router right? But I need a certain firmware depending on router's model or have any 'generic' option to redirect all http requests to another url/ip? I just need to redirect the http requests to another IP, maybe using the router to do this would be easier..

Comment: In order to have effective control over the user experience, you would likely have to do it at the router/firewall.  Twarting DNS at the desktop level would be too easy to circumvent. You favorite search engine can answer your additional question if you search for "captive portal".

Comment: MikeAWood: What if the server had two NICs? Router connected to one NIC, internal network connected to the other, both on different networks? This means the only machine with access to the external network would be the server forcing all desktops to use the server.